# ELMO embedding start session

Tags: nlp, embedding

I have an error when I apply the Elmo embedding to my data. I have 7255 sentences.

```
embeddings = embed(
    sentences,
    signature="default",
    as_dict=True)['default']

#Start a session and run ELMo to return the embeddings in variable x
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(tf.tables_initializer())
  x = sess.run(embeddings)
```

The error is:

> ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[36021075,50] and type int32 on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 by allocator cpu
>        [[node module_apply_default/map/TensorArrayStack/TensorArrayGatherV3 (defined at C:\Users...\envs\tf_36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_hub\native_module.py:547) ]]
>   Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

Answer (score 1):

ELMo is a large model. There are 2048-dimensional word embeddings, 4096-dimensional LSTM states in 2 layers and 2 directions. Only this is 18k floats, 71 kB per word (and there is much more: intermediate projections in LSTMs, character level CNN for word representation). You have 7,255 sentences, the average sentence has 25 words, this gives 12 GB RAM, but it is a very conservative estimate.

You need to split the sentences into batches and process the batches iteratively. There are many ways how to do that and I don't what implementation you use and what exactly is in variable `sentences`. But you probably can call [`tf.split`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split) on `sentences` and get a list of objects for which call session independently or if you use `tf.dataset`, you can use batching provided by the dataset API. You can always also split your data and use multiple input files.